# How to switch requirement snippet from var to const?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, jshint

I'm using atom and before whenever I hit tab for the req snippet I used to get a variable, now out of nowhere it switched to const, which I constantly have to switch, has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: hi there, the req snippet is for the require statement for importing npm packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: The Atom package that provides JavaScript snippets, `language-javascript`, was updated and [had its behavior changed](https://github.com/atom/language-javascript/commit/8d131e00325092e6476e78fcf3e6cc5423e130cf) to use `const` instead of `var`.

If you want to switch back, you can manually add this to your snippets file (under **Edit → Snippets...**):

```coffee
'.source.js':
  'CommonJS require':
    'prefix': 'req'
    'body': 'var ${1:module} = require(\'${1:module}\');'
```